# Contruct a logarithmic scale for hist and boxplot

Tags: r, plot

I need your help because I want to have a logarithmic scale for my histogram and boxplot.
The problem is that I have many observation which are concentrate in a little interval, and I think using logarithmic scale will solve my issue.
For example,

```
x <- c(1:5000)
y <- c(rnorm(x),0)
z <- c(exp(y^2 +5*y),0)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(z, main="Histogramme des durées",
     ylab="Fréquences")
boxplot(z, main="Boîtes des durées")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

It's very difficult to analyze my data, so I tried to add log = "x" but it don't do what I want !

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of scaling the plot axis, you could plot the logarithm of the data.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(log(z), main="Histogramme des durées",ylab="Fréquences")
boxplot(log(z), main="Boîtes des durées")
```

If you want the axis scale to be in the original units (not logarithmic units), you can change the axis tick labels.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(log10(z), xaxt='n',xlab='',main="Histogramme des durées",ylab="Fréquences")
atx <- axTicks(1)
labels <- sapply(atx,function(i)
        as.expression(bquote(10^.(i) ))
       )
axis(1,at=atx,labels=labels)

boxplot(log10(z),yaxt='n', ylab='z',main="Boîtes des durées")
aty <- axTicks(2)
labels <- sapply(aty,function(i)
        as.expression(bquote(10^.(i) ))
      )
axis(2,at=aty,labels=labels)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding ! I already tried it, but I want to change the axis scale. For example, if I had marks of student, it's not pratical to change in "log".